# Lock camera X orientation when device orientation changes Kotlin

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, android-camerax

I would like to prevent my camera X preview from rotation when my device orientation changes, but the rest of my UI should be rotated (landscape or portrait).

I have actually built my app in Flutter but i have implemented the camera X in Kotlin.
I can't just "prevent" the screen orientation changes as i actually want my UI to be rotated.
The only alternative i have found is building 2 UIs myself (portrait / landscape) and rotating when listening to a gyroscopic event...

I have tried to do the following without success :

```
<androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:id="@+id/camera_view"/>
```

I am looking for a method such as :

```
Preview preview = new Preview.Builder().setTargetResolution(size).setTargetRotation(Surface.ROTATION_90).build();
preview.lockOrientation(); // This line
preview.setSurfaceProvider(cameraPreview.getSurfaceProvider());
```

Thanks in advance